# Laurent series of $\frac{z}{\sin({\frac{\pi}{z+1}})}$ in the roots of the denominator

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'd like to compute the first few terms of the Laurent series of $\frac{z}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{z+1})}$ at $z=\frac{1}{k}-1, k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
I assume I know the espansion of $\frac{1}{\sin{z}}$ in $z=0$, so i'm trying to express $\frac{\pi}{z+1}$ in terms of $[z-(\frac{1}{k}-1)], k\in\mathbb{Z}$, but I can't get anything useful to be put in the expansion of $\frac{1}{\sin{z}}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $z=w+\left(\frac1k-1\right)$ then
$$
f(z)=F(w)=\frac{w+\left(\frac1k-1\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{w+\frac1k}\right)}=\frac{w+\left(\frac1k-1\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{1+kw}\right)}
$$
Now recall that the expansion of $k\pi(1+kw)^{-1}$ at $0$: for $|w|<\frac1k$,
$$
\frac{k\pi}{1+kw}=k\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n k^nw^n=\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n k^{n+1}w^n
$$
and, for $v \in \mathbb{C}$,
$$
\sin(v)=v-\frac{v^3}{3!}+\frac{v^5}{5!}-\dots\tag{1}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: not really, either if I use $1/\sin{x}=1/x+x/6+7/360x^3+O{x^5}$ and then expand the geometric series or if I expand the the geometric series and the $\sin$ at denominator for the first few terms and then perform long division I only seem to get powers of w with positive exponent. Could you please write some more of what you meant to do?

Comment: @EugenioDiPaola Let $$v:=\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n k^{n+1}w^n$$ and then plug it in equation $(1)$ of my answer.

Comment: $$\sin{\left(\frac{k\pi}{1-(-kw)}\right)}=\sin{\left[k\pi^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n k^{n+1}w^n}\right]}={k\pi^2\left[k-k^2 w+O(w^2)\right]-\frac{k^3\pi^6}{6^3}\left[k-k^2 w+O(w^2)\right]^3+k\pi^2 O[(k-k^2 w+O(w^2))^5]} =k\pi+k^6 \frac{\pi^6}{6^3}+O(k^5)$$, which doesn't contain any $w$